# jGit fetch error: cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: android, git, jgit

So I'm working with legacy code in an app I'm fixing up. The code uses jGit to pull a repo on startup. During the fetch call, I'm passing in the URL which is something like:

```
https://thisone@git.hungry.androider.com/myrepo.git
```

Problem is, when I make the fetch call, I get an error saying:

```
cannot open git-upload-pack
```

I noticed a few SO answers say to use a ProxySelector, but I noticed that in the ProxySelector, the select(Uri) call is being passed the following URI:

```
https://thisone@git.hungry.androider.com/myrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

My question is, where and why is

```
/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

being added to my url/uri?

And how can I overcome this error?

Below is the full stack trace:

> 10-14 10:45:28.469 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://fugutest@git.sports.atimi.com/ahl-hershey-bears-qa.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
>   10-14 10:45:28.481 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
>   10-14 10:45:28.492 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:261)
>   10-14 10:45:28.504 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.atimi.caviar.CaviarGitRepo$UpdateRunnable.update(CaviarGitRepo.java:577)
>   10-14 10:45:28.515 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.atimi.caviar.CaviarGitRepo$UpdateRunnable.run(CaviarGitRepo.java:441)
>   10-14 10:45:28.526 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   10-14 10:45:28.541 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err: Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://fugutest@git.sports.atimi.com/ahl-hershey-bears-qa.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
>   10-14 10:45:28.562 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:524)
>   10-14 10:45:28.571 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:309)
>   10-14 10:45:28.580 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
>   10-14 10:45:28.589 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
>   10-14 10:45:28.597 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1138)
>   10-14 10:45:28.606 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
>   10-14 10:45:28.611 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:    ... 4 more
>   10-14 10:45:28.625 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "/ahl-hershey-bears-qa.git/info/refs": No address associated with hostname
>   10-14 10:45:28.659 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
>   10-14 10:45:28.668 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>   10-14 10:45:28.677 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>   10-14 10:45:28.686 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>   10-14 10:45:28.697 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>   10-14 10:45:28.706 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>   10-14 10:45:28.715 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>   10-14 10:45:28.724 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>   10-14 10:45:28.735 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
>   10-14 10:45:28.746 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
>   10-14 10:45:28.757 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
>   10-14 10:45:28.769 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>   10-14 10:45:28.780 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>   10-14 10:45:28.790 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:98)
>   10-14 10:45:28.799 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:168)
>   10-14 10:45:28.808 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:475)
>   10-14 10:45:28.813 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:    ... 9 more
>   10-14 10:45:28.830 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
>   10-14 10:45:28.899 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>   10-14 10:45:28.909 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
>   10-14 10:45:28.919 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
>   10-14 10:45:28.923 25237-25462/com.atimi.sportsapp W/System.err:    ... 24 more

Comment: Do you actually need a proxy server to connect to the remote host? Please also clarify if the error occured before you used a `ProxySelector`.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, yes it did occur before adding the ProxyServer code

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann added

Comment: Did you see the `UnknownHostException`? It seems the URL is malformed or misinterpreted. BTW the stack trace is barely readable with each lined prefixed.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after you requested it lol. Need to figure out why THAT's happening now...